# Copy $Logs container data to another Blob location

Tags: azure-storage

We have a requirement wherein we need to merge all $logs of all storage accounts into a single blob.

I heard we can use AzCopy but is there any other simple way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Azure data factory to achieve it.
The $logs container; which is automatically created when Storage Analytics is enabled for a storage account is not displayed when a container listing operation is performed via Data Factory UI. The file path must be provided directly for Data Factory to consume files from the $logs container.